# Figuring out the angle difference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The camera rotates around a point and I can move it up and down relative to the camera.
I try to find out the angle difference to limit the users input to move the camera up and down.
I don't care about the Z axis so I remove that from desiredRotation.

The problem is that when it only rotate around and not moving up and down the angleDifference changes.

```
camTransform.RotateAround(target.position, transform.forward, 5);

Quaternion desiredRotation = Quaternion.Euler(camTransform.eulerAngles.x + (-rotation.y), camTransform.eulerAngles.y, 0);

float angleDifference = Quaternion.Angle(desiredRotation, Quaternion.identity);

// I haven't set up any check to see if angleDifference is valid yet
camTransform.Rotate(-rotation.y, 0, 0, Space.Self);
```

Comment: I didn't completely undesrtand what exactly your goal is and at which point you struggle .. could you explain a bit more what exactly should happen? `The camera rotates around a point and I can move it up and down relative to the camera.`  if the camera rotates around that point .. than what does `move it up and down relative to the camera` mean?

Comment: Moving it up and down is in reference to the last line of code that that rotates the camera in the X axis and using Space.Self it dosn't take global space into account. 

What i have done is calculate angle difference, but the problemis that it slightly changes overtime which it shouldn't.

Comment: Here is a visual example of the angle difference slightly changes: https://streamable.com/1mthw

My question is why that is.

Comment: Nevermind i solved it
I replaced camTransform for the cameras parent transform in the first line and that resolved the issue